# 0 reputation, what are my possibilities?

Tags: discussion

Sorry already for the question, I'm sure it must be somewhere, yet I did not find it somehow. What can I do with 0 reputation? Can I really only ask questions? I would really like to contribute by upvoting and commenting. Yet I am rather new to ubuntu, so all my errors and mistakes have been asked before so far. And if there is a solution that worked for me but has only 5 upvotes so far, I want to show my appreciation by a vote up. Is that too much to ask for?

So with 0 reputation what exactly can I do? Can I only ask a question? I do not seem to be able to asnwer questions or at least I have not yet found where that is possible, but please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I had the exact same question so I started it as a discussion topic on meta. That thread is now a helpful answer: [http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16710/contributing-as-a-new-member-in-this-mature-stackexchange-site](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16710/contributing-as-a-new-member-in-this-mature-stackexchange-site)

Comment: as an aside, your upvotes (and downvotes) are recorded by the system, even though they don't affect the score of the post. There is [a SEDE data query that shows anonymous feedback](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/542845/anonymous-feedback-on-a-users-posts)